# Functions with rational image of algebraic elements

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Does there exist a non constant continuous fonction $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that for any real algebraic number $x$, $f(x)$ is rational?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Def'n : A linear  order $<_S$ on a set $S$ is order-dense iff $\forall x,y\in S\;(x<_S y\implies$ $ \exists z\;(x<_Sz<_Sy)).$

Theorem.(Cantor). If $S$ is countably infinite and $<_S$ is an order-dense linear order on $S$ with no end-points (no $<_S$ max or min) then there is an order-isomorphism from $S$ to $Q .$

So let $S$ be the algebraic reals, and let $<_S$ be the usual (real-number) order on $S.$ Let $f:S\to Q$ be an order-isomorphism. For non-algebraic real $r$ let $f(r)=\sup \{f(s):r>s\in S\}.$

Comment: Very interesting. How do you ensure the continuity with this definition of $f$? I don't see it, although it may have something to do with the monotony/density properties of your function.

Comment: @Vincent.  Show that $\sup \{f(y):x<y\}=\sup \{f(y):x>y\in S\}$ $\leq f(x)\leq $  $\leq \inf \{f(y):x<y\}=\inf \{f(y):x<y\in S\}$  and that $\sup \{f(y):x>y\in S\}=\inf \{f(y):x<y\in S\}$ by  using the density of $S$ and of $Q$ in the reals. So $ f$  is monotonic and continuous.